# Extracting validation logic into a method for reuse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery validation plugin and is working fine. I have validation logic duplicated in two places one is on form submit and the other is on focus out. Now i am trying to extract it into a method and reuse it whereever it is required. I am trying as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     validateForm();  

    function validateForm(){
            $("#myForm").validate({
              onfocusout: function(element) { jQuery(element).valid(); } ,
              rules:{
                attribute: "required"
            },
            messages:{
                attribute: "Required field"
            }
        });

      }


   $('#myForm #submit').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();


    var validator = validateForm();  //here it shows error line

    if(validator.form()){ 
          //do something
        }
});


});
```

If i extract the logic as above i am getting script error as below.

```
Error: 'Undefined' is null or not an object
```

Do i need to return anything from the method?

Thanks!

Comment: _I am using jquery validation plugin and is working fine_. I don't think so, you are calling a function that hasn't been defined yet. Sorry but this is a messy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with the validation plugin, but I can tell you the reason you are getting the reference error is because `validateForm()` returns `undefined` automatically when it finishes executing.

I'm guessing that `form()` is a method of the object `$().validate()` returns, if so all you need to do is make `validateForm()` return the result of `validate()` like so

```
function validateForm(){
    return $("#myForm").validate({ /* options */ });
}
```

Good luck!

Edit: Also, why are you invoking `validateForm()` on document ready - surely the form is just whatever was in the markup at that point...

Answer (score 0):

You assign validator variable the result of calling validateForm function. Function that does not have return statement returns *undefined* by default. And I don't see, where you define form method.

You could add a parameter to your validateForm function - id of form you want to validate and write it like:

```
function validateForm(id) {
    $(id)...
}
```

and then call it

```
validateForm('#myForm');
```

or

```
$('#anotherForm #submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateForm('#anotherForm');
}
```